# Give layer scenes their own color overlay, but keep the hireachy of whats in front and in the back

Tags: compositing-nodes, render-layers, layers

[image: Blender compositing setup]I have this example scene with Cubes, Cylinders and Spheres, split into 3 different layer scenes.
I split them up so I in the Compositing can give the different objects a specific color overlay.

The issue is I don't know how to combine them all again after giving them each a color overlay.
If I try to do that all the cubes will for example get in front.